# How to specify the special control char for delimiter?

Tags: neo4j

I have some files got from hive which use '\001' for delimiter. But I failed using neo4j-importer to import nodes and edges. How can I specify '\001' correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now afaik it's not possible to specify it.

If you're able to run java you might call

`org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(args)`

and provide as part of your args

`..., "--delimiter", String.valueOf((char)0), ...`

Comment: Do you have any idea about the long-time no-activity when I imported 24GB nodes file and 300GB edges file using Neo4jImport ? It frozen nearly two hours after I have imported 372M nodes. Is it normal?